# How to get specific value from react Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the ID of the specific input that is selected. I have a handleInputChange function that sets state that i want to send to the DB, what i need is to get the specific ID that is Selected.

```
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name)
    console.log(event.target.value)
    console.log(this.props.posts)
    this.setState({
     [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
     postId: **What do I put here to get the value id**
    })
 }
```

In my render i would like to get the value of post.id whenever they type in the input field

```
render () {
const reversedProps = this.props.posts.reverse();

const {title, postBody} = this.state
const displayGifPicker = this.state.displayGifPicker
return (
  <Grid item xl={8}>
    {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>
      <PostBodyTemplate key={index} postId={post.id} onChange= 
 {this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
       )} 
 </Grid>
)
}

}




const mt4 = {
  marginTop: '40px',
  height: '350px',
  marginBottom: '40px'
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  }
});

class NewPostBody extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      commentBody: null,
      postId: null,
      giphyUrl: null,
      postPicture: null,
      userId: null,
      userIdto: null,
      userIdName: null,
      userIdtoName:null,
      // postBody: null,
      // giphyUrl: null,
      // userIdto: null,
      // userIdName: null,
      // userIdtoName:'Julio',

      displayGifPicker: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchPosts();

}

  handleInputChange = (event, id) => {
    console.log(event.target.name)
    console.log(event.target.value)
    console.log(this.props.posts)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      postId: id

    })
  }

  displayGifPicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      displayGifPicker: !this.state.displayGifPicker
    })
}

getGifState = (selectedUrl) => {
  this.setState({ giphyUrl: selectedUrl})
}

  render () {
    const reversedProps = this.props.posts.reverse();

    const {title, postBody} = this.state
    const displayGifPicker = this.state.displayGifPicker
    return (
      <Grid item xl={8}>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>
          <PostBodyTemplate key={index} postId={post.id} onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e,post.id)} />
           )} 
     </Grid>
    )
  }

}

NewPostBody.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // user: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  // user: state.user.items,
  posts: state.posts.items,

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(NewPostBody);
```

This is the PostBodyTemplate

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
  },
}));

const fr = {
  float: 'right'
}

const giphyRes = {
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px'
}

         export default function PostBodyTemplate(props, onChange, onSubmit) {

             const classes = useStyles();
            //  render() {
                 return (
                    <Grid item xs={12} xl={8} lg={8} style={fr}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <CardContent>
                    <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" style={fr}>
                          {props.userWhoPosted} Gave A VH5 To Julio {props.postId}
                      </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                          {props.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                          {props.postBody}
                        </Typography>
                        <img src={props.giphyUrl} style={giphyRes}/>
                    </Paper>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                    <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                        <FavoriteIcon />
                        <div>Add Gif</div>
                      </IconButton>
                      <IconButton aria-label="share">
                        <EcoIcon />
                        <div>Add Photo</div>
                      </IconButton>
                      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <div className={classes.container}>
                        <TextField
                                   onChange = {onChange}
                                    name='commentBody'
                                    id="standard-full-width"
                                    label="Reply To Post"
                                    style={{ margin: 8 }}
                                    placeholder="Reply to Post"
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="normal"
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                    shrink: true,
                                    }}
                            />
                          {/* <p><button>Send VH5</button></p> */}
                          <Button onSubmit={onSubmit} size="small">Submit</Button>
                        {/* <button onSubmit={onSubmit}>Submit Reply</button> */}

                        </div>
                      </form>
                      {/* <CommentInput onChange={onChange}/> */}
                      {/* <Button size="small">Submit</Button> */}
                    </CardActions>
                    <Paper className={classes.root} value={props.postId}>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                        {props.commentBody}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                          {props.userIdName} replied to the post. 
                        </Typography>
                    </Paper>
                  </Card>
                  </Grid>
                 )
            //  }
         }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but binding `handleInputChange` like this is pointless since it's already an arrow function. (Even if it wasn't an arrow function you'd want to bind it in the constructor, not at every render.) The naive solution is to use something like `() => handleInputChange(index)` as the click handler.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I was copy and pasting previous code.

Comment: Hi you could bind you function `handleInputChange` it in your constructor because here you are binding your function everytime your component re-renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it to your handler

```
  <PostBodyTemplate onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e,post.id)} />
```

And inside `handleChange`

```
handleInputChange = (event, id) => {
    console.log(event.target.name)
    console.log(event.target.value)
    console.log(this.props.posts)
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        postId: id
    })
}
```

Notice that You're already using `arrow function` notation, so you don't need to `bind`.

You're also receiving `props` incorrectly inside `PostBodyTemplate`. The following

```
export default function PostBodyTemplate(props, onChange, onSubmit)
```

Should be

```
export default function PostBodyTemplate({onChange, onSubmit}){}
```

Or

```
export default function PostBodyTemplate(props){
    const { onChange, onSubmit} = props
}
```

Comment: When I do this i get the following errors: "Invalid prop `onChange` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected `function`"  and "Uncaught TypeError: onChange.apply is not a function"

Comment: `onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e,post.id)}` using this syntax?

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work. I used that code and it gives the errors

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work. I used that code and it gives the errors

Comment: Post the entire component please.

Comment: Just posted it to check

Comment: You are receveing prop in the wrong way. Updated the answer